# getAccessTokenAsync does not cause fiddler traffic

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

When I execute in the F12 console of my Outlook 2016 add-in the call `Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function(token {console.log(token)}))`, the result returned is

```js
error:{
    code: 13007,
    message: "An unexpected error occurred on the server.",
    name: "Authentication Provider Error"
},
status: "failed",
value: undefined
```

However, I now wanted to see what exactly goes over the wire, and used fiddler with HTTPS decryption. It tells me that no call are made at all between the issuance of the call and the output of the result.

Why could that be?

Comment: What is the full version and build number of your Outlook client?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a typo in your question but the correct format would be `function (token) {` not `function (token {` (note the closing `)` after token).

Comment: It's Outlook 16.0.8431.2107, and yes, that was a typo. (I cannot copy and paste from one computer to the other, and I have to test on a non-production Outlook because the production Outlook is hooked up to an Exchange 2013 server which does not support navigation pane add-ins).

Comment: I've never gotten Fiddler to show the call from the Office host application to AAD. You might try using the Charles tool instead. There's a link to it in this topic: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins .  You should also take a look at that article for the 13007 error.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and found that the problem was with my AAD Application. SSO API requires you to create a V2 App but my App was created as a V1. For a V2 App, the following values must be set and can be verified in the App Manifest from Azure portal:
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount", 
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2